# What is Case._LightningUpdateCase quick action?

Tags: lightning, lightning-components, lightning-record-page

Good day,
I've noticed in my org, that there is a Related Record component on the Case lightning page that show that case data, but the strange thing there is that in 'Update Action' of that Related Record component the action is selected that doesn't exists in 'Buttons, links and actions' settings. When I look at the page xml, that component is shown like that

```
<componentInstance>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>createQuickActionName</name>
                <value>NewCase</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>lookupFieldName</name>
                <value>Id</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentInstanceProperties>
                <name>updateQuickActionName</name>
                <value>Case._LightningUpdateCase</value>
            </componentInstanceProperties>
            <componentName>console:relatedRecord</componentName>
            <identifier>console_relatedRecord</identifier>
        </componentInstance>
```

with the quick action name Case._LightningUpdateCase, which seems to be strange.
Now I need to update fields on that component and I wonder where can I do that, where to look for that strange quick action?